# getting outdated value for [@unittest.skipIf decorator] condition

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator

I just encountered a problem with `@unittest.skipIf(expression)`. Well, the problem is that if I use variable in decorator that is declared and assigned a value before starting the test, and during the test the value of this variable is changed the effect is such that decorator includes the old value. For example:

```python
class Settings(object):
    flag=False
class TestCase(object):

    # during the test variable is changed (in this module or another)
    Settings.flag=True

    @unittest.skipIf(Settings.flag==True)
    def test_something(self):
        ...
```

Value of `Settings.flag` can be changed in another module or this module (this doesn't matter). In both cases condition `Setting.flag==True` during call `test_something` still takes the 'False' value although it was already changed to 'True' value. It is very strange and I admit that I don't understand how this mechanism works. It seems that the value used in this decorator can't be changed during the test. Maybe there is some other interesting way to skip the test at the time of a particular condition, which may change during the test. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to skip a test if `flag` is true. It is true, so you skip the test. Later, you change `flag` -- and you want to go back in time and magically "unskip" it?

Comment: No. Default value is FALSE, during the test value is changing on TRUE but `skipIf ` reads this value still as FALSE. Value is changing before `test_something` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. Function arguments are evaluated when the function is called. The decorator is a function that's called when the function being decorated is defined. Therefore, the flag is tested when the decorated function is defined. The decorator has no way to know what the test even was; it only sees `True` or `False` (or more likely, truthiness or falsiness) so it can't store the condition away for later evaluation.

For `skipIf()` to work as you want, it would need to take a function (e.g. `lambda: Settings.flag==True`) rather than a Boolean value. Then it would be able to evaluate this condition later, when the decorated function is actually called. But it doesn't actually work that way. (This would probably be an easy enhancement to add, though.)

You may be able to work around this by not importing the module containing your unit tests until after the value of `Settings.flag` has been established. This will defer the definition (and thus the decoration) of your test functions until then, and the decorator will have access to the desired value of the flag. Not knowing how your code is structured, I don't know whether this is practical for you.

Additionally, something looks fishy about `Settings.flag==True`... can't quite put my finger on it... ;-)

Comment: `@unittest.skipIf(lambda test=Settings.flag: True if test==True else False, "Test skipped")` won't work as I expect, it still got FALSE value. Can you give a sample how to use lambda in decorator. Maybe I'm doing smething wrong

Comment: Sorry, for example above I still got TRUE value of course. Doesn't matter - problem still exists. Value is changing and decorator with lambda statement still receives old value.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear: `skipIf()` would need to be written to accept a function; it isn't, so (like most objects in Python) a function is `True` to it.